# How to test a git-crypt encrypted repo with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, encryption, jenkins-pipeline

The tests I run with Jenkins (multi-branch pipeline) on my repo make use of an encrypted file (`keys.py`) in it, via `git-crypt`. In order to use that file locally, I usually use `git-crypt unlock`, but I cannot directly add this step to the Jenkinsfile because of how that command works:

1. `gpg` is used to decrypt the symmetric key used for encrypting my file (i.e. `.git-crypt/keys/default/0/xxxx.gpg`). This key is encrypted with RSA, using my private key, and this one has a passphrase which you are **prompted** to enter when trying to use it.
2. Decrypts `keys.py` using the decrypted key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the issue of the prompt, run the `git-crypt` steps manually inserting
your passphrase as a command-line argument to `gpg` and the decrypted symmetric
key to `git-crypt unlock`. Here we make use of a few more tricks that will 
ease your life like the use of the Jenkins [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

`gpg --no-tty --passphrase YOUR_PASSPHRASE_GOES_HERE --output $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/decrypted.gpg --decrypt $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/YOUR_KEY_FILE_GOES_HERE.gpg && git-crypt unlock $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/decrypted.gpg`

Here we raise a second issue, and it is that executing this twice will raise an
error as well. We want the repo to be decrypted only when it is encrypted. In
order to solve that, first check that the file containing the symmetric key
exists, generated only during the previous step. In the end, we end up with a
stage that looks like:

`stage('Unlock repo') {
    steps {
        script {
            sh("[ -f $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/decrypted.gpg ] || gpg --no-tty --passphrase YOUR_PASSPHRASE_GOES_HERE --output $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/decrypted.gpg --decrypt $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/YOUR_KEY_FILE_GOES_HERE.gpg && git-crypt unlock $WORKSPACE/.git-crypt/keys/default/0/decrypted.gpg")
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I find this solution kind of ugly, as it works but includes the passphrase for my private key in the Jenkinsfile, which is uploaded as plaintext to a git repository, and the way it checks whether to do the unlock looks verbose and kind of unreadable. If someone has a better idea than this please contribute!

Comment: using jenkins secret text credentials you can obfuscate the password and the keyfile name, since those shouldn't change unless you change them.

Answer (score 1):

I've build another solution for git-crypt by creating a separate container with `git-crypt` and invoke these in stages before and after the main build step:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
       // $HOME is not set in build-agent
       JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = '-Duser.home=/home/jenkins/'
    }
    agent {
        label 'docker'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Decrypt') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'wjung/jenkins-git-crypt:latest'
                    registryUrl 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
                    registryCredentialsId 'docker-hub'
                }
            }
            steps {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'git-crypt-key', variable: 'FILE')]) {
                    sh 'cd $WORKSPACE; git-crypt unlock $FILE'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build docker image') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-jdk-11'
                    args '-v /services/maven/m2:/home/jenkins/.m2 -v /services/maven/m2/cache:/home/jenkins/.cache'
                }
            }
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'mvn-setting-xml', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -B -Dmaven.test.skip clean deploy'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Lock dir') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'wjung/jenkins-git-crypt:latest'
                    registryUrl 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
                    registryCredentialsId 'docker-hub'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'cd $WORKSPACE; git-crypt lock'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The encryption key is exported from the repository by `git-crypt export-key TMPFILE` and later added as secret file with id: `git-crypt-key`.